# react native blog feed view

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i'm creating react native app and on it's first page(Home page) it will show some content of blog feeds and on clicking Read more it will show the detailed view of that blog feed on the next page. So, my question is how to do it ?
Here is my output:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PAY.png)

So on clicking read more button it should open the detailed view of  only that blog feed and my question is how to do it in react native?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  ListView,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions, Router, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import TimeAgo from 'react-native-timeago';
import {
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Content,
  Header,
  Body,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Container,
  Left,
  Icon,
  Right
} from 'native-base';

import {GetImage,ContentSnippet} from './helpers/helpers';
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';
import FitImage from 'react-native-fit-image';
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()       {
          return fetch('http://www.cardory.co.uk/jan/json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !==             
 r2});
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.items),
    }, function() {
      // do something with new state
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 80}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }

return (
  <Container style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 60}} >
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData) =>

      <Card>
        <CardItem header>
          <Text style={styles.titleHeading}>{rowData.title}</Text>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem cardBody>
            <Content style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}}>
              <FitImage source={{uri: GetImage(rowData.content_html)}}/>
              <HTMLView value={ContentSnippet(rowData.content_html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,""))}/>
            </Content>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem>
            <Left>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.details}>
                <Text>
                  Read more
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Left>
            <Right>
              <Text>
                <Icon name="time"/>
                <TimeAgo time=  {rowData.date_published}/>
              </Text>
            </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    }
  />
  </Container>
);
    }
  }
  const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    textHeading:{
      fontSize:20,
      marginTop:20
    },
    titleHeading:{
      fontSize:20,
      fontWeight:'bold',
      color:'black',
      alignItems:'center',
    }
  });
  module.export=Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a navigation library, eg. [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org).

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class Home extends Component {
  // your code
  // ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { rowData })}>
  // ...
}

class Detail extends Component {
  // detail view logic
  // the rowData will be available at this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData
}

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Detail: { screen: Detail },
})

export default App
```

edit: I just realized you're already using a navigation library (react-native-router-flux). I think react-navigation is easier to start with.

Comment: But my question is how to read only that specific blog feed on clicking read more button  as every post has read more button and on clicking that button it should open the detailed view of only that post .

Comment: This example makes exactly what you want. The navigation.navigate pushes the screen to the detailed view from the list.

Comment: Sir, how are you using this logic? Actually my question is how it will show the detailed view of exactly that blog post ? is (this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData) is responsible for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can pass params to the detail view with the navigation.navigate's second argument. At this example the rowData has passed, and you can access it as this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.

Comment: Sir, it is giving an error in my case. Would you please tell me how to do this using react-native-router-flux?